# Retrieving Data Based on User Click Event with JSON API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm building an employee directory using AJAX/jQuery leveraging the Random User Employee Directory API.  This is the actual data feed i'm using:

https://randomuser.me/api/?results=12&format=json

I have successfully retrieved and displayed a page full of sample employees.  But I'm having an issue in showing an individual's record (via modal) if a user clicks on a record. `Console log` is saying `"Cannot read property 'cell' of undefined"`.  I'm pretty confident that this is due to the `displayModal` function not being able to access the data from the json call in the `'employees'` variable.  I've tried moving that function inside of the `$ajax` call where I'm retrieving the data, but that doesn't work--so not sure where to go from here.

[jfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cdogstu99/dt48kxvs/2/)

```
//Get JSON DATA and stored data in variable Employees.
var employees;

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=12&format=json',

    success: function(data){
        employees = data.results;
        displayEmployees(employees);
        console.log(employees);
    }
});

//Create Function to Build Employee Car
function displayEmployees(employees){
    var employeesHTML = ""
    $.each(employees, function(i, employee) {
        employeesHTML += '<div class="employee" employee-id="' + employee.id.value + '>';
        employeesHTML += '<a href="">';
        employeesHTML += '<img class="employee-photo" src="' + employee.picture.large + '"></a>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="info">';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="name">'+ employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last + '</div>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="email grey-font">'+ employee.email + '</div>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="city grey-font">' + employee.location.city + '</div></div></div>';
           });

    $('.employees').html(employeesHTML);

};

//Create Function to Build Modal
function displayModal(employees, id){
    var employeesModal;
    //create modal
    employeesModal += '<div>' + employees[id].cell + '</div';

    $('.modal-text').html(employeesModal);

}

//Click Event To Display Modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
$('.employees').on("click", ".employee", function() {
    $.each(employees, function(i, employee) {
        var id = $(this).attr('employee-id');
        modal.style.display = "block";
        displayModal(employees, id);
        console.log('click');
    });
});

// // When the user clicks on (x), close the modal
$('.close').on("click", function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
});

// // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}


console.log(employees);
```

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr('data-id');` is returning `NaN` so it cannot find the employee by index because `NaN` won't work

Comment: It doesn't look like that attribute is being set when you build the HTML elements

Comment: If you're going to use data, use jQuery's `data` method: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: If you could update your fiddle please, otherwise try this: using `parseInt(id)` because values coming out of the DOM are always strings

Comment: ok thx updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cdogstu99/dt48kxvs/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
//Get JSON DATA and stored data in variable Employees.
var employees;

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=12&format=json',
    success: function(data){
     employees = data.results;
     displayEmployees(employees);
 }
});
//Create Function to Build Employee Car
function displayEmployees(employees){
 var employeesHTML = ""
 $.each(employees, function(i, employee) {
  employeesHTML += '<div class="employee">';
     employeesHTML += '<a href="">';
     employeesHTML += '<img class="employee-photo" src="' + employee.picture.large + '"></a>';
     employeesHTML += '<div class="info">';
     employeesHTML += '<div class="name">'+ employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last + '</div>';
     employeesHTML += '<div class="email grey-font">'+ employee.email + '</div>';
     employeesHTML += '<div class="city grey-font">' + employee.location.city + '</div></div></div>';
        });

    $('.employees').html(employeesHTML);

};

//Create Function to Build Modal
function displayModal(employees){
 var employeesModal="";
 //create modal
    employeesModal += '<div>' + $(employees).html() + '</div>';

    $('.modal-text').html(employeesModal);
}

//Click Event To Display Modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
$('.employees').on("click", ".employee", function() {
   var current = $(this);
     modal.style.display = "block";
     displayModal(current);
});

// // When the user clicks on (x), close the modal
$('.close').on("click", function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
});

// // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto'; font-size:12px;
    color:gray;
}


ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.employees {
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;

  /* Then we define the flow direction
     and if we allow the items to wrap
   * Remember this is the same as:
   * flex-direction: row;
   * flex-wrap: wrap;
   */
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: space-around;

  width:100%;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 82px;
  margin-top:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:14px;
  }

.employee {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color:black;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 7px;
  }


.info {
    float:right;
    display: block;
    font-size:12px;
    width:40%;
    height: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    top: -14%;
    left: 47%;
    text-align: left;
    }

.employee-photo{
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px -159px;
}

.name{height:30px; font-size:15px;}

.email{height:30px;}

.city{height: 30px}

.grey-font{
  color: #888;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 25%;
    height: 60%; 
    position:absolute;
    top:-25%;
    left:38%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      

<body>



<div class="title">AWESOME STARTUP EMPLOYEE DIRECTORY</div>

<div class="employees">

</div>

<!-- Set Div For Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal Content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-text">Some text in the Modal..</div>
</div>
</div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

Just modify the css to display it right.

Comment: very cool--the one question i have:  In the modal I actually have to display some other fields from the JSON data that are not on the main employee card.  how exactly can i do that here?   for example i tried $(employees.phone).html() but get an undefined

Comment: what is phone?.

Comment: phone number (just a test variable for now) but can see field here https://randomuser.me/api/?results=12&format=json

Comment: when you get the json data do you also insert the phone to an element?

Comment: no was just storing all of the employees like this: employees = data.results;

Comment: @JohnRogerson how about you store it also in the html but its hidden and display it when its in the modal..

Comment: I was just thinking of that.  I'll give it a go.  Thanks!